# Python: appengine urllib2 headers from a 302

Tags: python, google-app-engine, header, urllib2

A normal `urllib2` works fine:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> r = urllib2.urlopen(u"http://bit.ly/4ovTZw")
>>> r.geturl()
'http://www.writing.com/main/handler/action/show_document/item_id/933413.mp3'
>>> r.headers.get("Content-Type")
'audio/mpeg'
```

But in appengine, the same code shows `text/html`.

```
def get(self):
    r = urllib2.urlopen(u"http://bit.ly/4ovTZw")
    self.response.out.write( r.geturl() )
    self.response.out.write( r.headers.get("Content-Type") )
    return
```

Can I get around this? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried to call that specifi url via [Interactive Shell](http://shell.appspot.com/); it works for me using the [urlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html) function.

```
Google App Engine/1.4.2
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, May 12 2010, 14:18:27) 
[GCC 4.3.1]

>>> from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
>>> result = urlfetch.fetch('http://bit.ly/4ovTZw') 
>>> print result.headers['content-type']
audio/mpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

I know for a fact that AppEngine blacklists some addresses - check your response body for a hint.

It might also be the other way around - some services blacklist AppEngine... I am not sure.  I remember in the early days of GAE, accessing Delicious was not possible through AppEngine.